# How to mount Snappy Ubuntu Core writable on an external drive

Tags: mount, hard-drive, ubuntu-core

In another question ([Mounting a drive Ubuntu Snappy](https://askubuntu.com/questions/771295/mounting-a-drive-ubuntu-snappy/775334#775334)) part of the answer was - Another way is to actually place the writable partition on the external hard drive, which would allow all snaps to place their data there without them knowing any different.

I am wondering exactly how one would go about doing this?  Where is the fstab file to edit to change where /writable is mounted on?

Thanks in advance!

Ray.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way to do this.  First attach the external drive.  Second using parted make the label writable.  Create an ext4 partition and name it writable. Quit parted and use mkfs -t ext4 -L writable /dev/sd?1. Finally using fdisk delete partition #3 on /dev/sda.  Then reboot.

Comment: PS. you need to copy everything from the original /writable to the new file system before you delete partition #3 above!